# Dependent Dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, drop-down-menu

Hi everyone I'm fairly new and unfamiliar with JavaScript/Web Dev and I'm trying to make two dropdown menus, where the second menu changes depending on what they choose on the first one

for example

```
Choice1
Choice2
Choice3
```

and if they choose Choice1 the next drop down might be

```
Choice1.1
Choice1.2
```

and a follow up question would be, how can I get what the User chose?
This also does not have to be written in javascript.
Any help/resources/readings would be very helpful (I've tried doing google searches but I couldn't find anything)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created simple demo app for you, give it a try.

Further study reference

- http://api.jquery.com/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp
- https://api.jquery.com/change/ - To understand more on change event

```js
$("#select_1").on("change", function(evt) { //Using jQuery subscribe for change event of select_1  
  var $select_2 = $("#select_2");
  $select_2.empty(); //Empty the select before adding new items.
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $select_2.append($("<option>Sub choice " + $(this).val() + "__" + i + "</option>"));
  }
});

$("#select_1").change(); //Trigger change event on page load so that the second select gets properly set
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Choices</label>
<select id="select_1">
  <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
</select>

<BR />
<label>Sub Choices</label>
<select id="select_2">
  <option>Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you so much!
Time to study it, but could you explain what the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
is for?

Comment: That is include tag, in simple words that means that this javascript file will be downloaded with your HTML page and you can refer/use functions which are defined inside it in your code. For example:  $("#select_1") now in this line $ is jquery instance defined in the included file here # means select by id.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp